# Power BI missing MySQL Connector, even though I installed it

Tags: powerbi, mysql-connector

On my Windows 10, I downloaded Power BI today in order to pull data from my remote server, which is MySQL.

I go to "get data from other source", choose MySQL, and then get a prompt that "this connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used"

I installed both the latest NET and ODBC connector for windows, restarted my pc, but still get the same error.

How should I troubleshoot this?  Am I supposed to see something running in "services"?

Comment: Does the connector match the bitness of PowerBI (32 or 64-bit)? Here are some other suggestions: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Trying-to-connect-to-MY-SQL-from-Power-BI/td-p/195060

Comment: Connector net is X86 (dont see X64 option), and ODBC is X64. Both are version 8.0.32. 
My Power BI Version: 2.112.1161.0 64-bit (December 2022)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I managed to solve this by connecting using MariaDB instead of MySQL, and downloading the MariaDB connector. isn't that strange? any downsides for connecting this way?

Comment: Don't know, what have you found on the subject so far?

Comment: Also, if you found a solution that works for you, feel free to post it as an answer to your own question (with e.g. screenshots). It will make it easier for others with the same problem to resolve their issue.

Answer (score 3):

As of 4th July 2023, and from this website: [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/mysql-database)

It seems that we need to use version 8.0.26 .

Seems like you can donwload past versions from [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/)

However I must say that apparently the current version will work for me (8.0.33), I am just waiting for some help from my sysadmin to be able to access the server from my desktop.

Edit: Yes the newest version of the ODBC has worked for us, we are running PBI Version: 2.118.828.0 64-bit (June 2023) and ODBC 8.0.33 and it works

Edit2: the past version worked, until it didn't, the only way I could get that to work was installing the 8.0.26 as I suggested at the beginning. This can be done from the "MySql installer - community" installer though, you just need to select the 8.0.26 and that's it.

Comment: Thanks man. I had one extra good boyfriend points because i helped my gf fix this

Answer (score 1):

I have downgraded to 8.0.28 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of my desktop is :

**Windows 11 Home**

Processor: **AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics**
System: **64-bit operating system, x64-based processor**

The installed Power BI version is :
**2.122.746.0 64-bit (October 2023)**

I have tried several versions of MySQL Connector/NET like **8.0.26, 8.0.28, 8.1.0**

But still, I am getting the error "**This connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used**"

Comment: UPDATE: 

I solved this issue flowing this :

go to File | Options and Settings | Data source settings and edit your data source and set the credentials to "Database credentials", not Windows credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the installation of the latest version of the
connector like 8.0.29 or above.

Solution to fix it:

Step 1:

Uninstall the newer version by double-clicking on the downloaded file of the connector, selecting "uninstall," and following Step 2.
(Note, all you need to do is keep the latest version of MySQL, only uninstall the connector)

Step 2 (Install the older version):

Download version 8.0.28 from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/ and run the file.
(Note: only install connector)
During installation, select the "typical" option.
Restart your computer.

Close Power BI and restart your entire system to ensure the changes are applied. Please note that version 8.0.28 is currently the standard version, and it is recommended to use the typical option during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Power Bi Version 2.122.746.0 and after downgrading the ODBC Driver to 8.0.28 it working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It **worked** after I downgraded both connector/ODBC to 8.0.28 and Connector/net 8.0.28 and I am using power bi version 2.124.1554.0

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem, install older version, my newest is 8.3.0, but I installed 8.032. It helped, but I had a new error 'We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided.'. I solved this by usng not my current credentials, but database credentials that are placed right under Windows credentials on the left. Here you need to place username of ur server connection, for me it was 'root' and your password.